# GLFW "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64"

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, glfw

I recently got a M1 Macbook and am trying to write C++ Code.
I created a simple project with a main.cpp a makefile and a lib Folder with an GLFW Folder in it with two Header Files.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "lib/GLFW/glfw3.h"

#define GL_SILENCE_DEPRECATION

int main() {
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if (!glfwInit()){
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Test Window by Jonny", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
        glfwTerminate();
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);


    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

makefile:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL=main

main:
    clang++ main.cpp -I./lib/GLFW/ -o main
```

Now if I'm trying to run the makefile from the Terminal with *make* I get the following Error-Output:

```
solon  20:17  ~/D/0/C/_/Graphics  > make
clang++ main.cpp -I./lib/GLFW/ -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_glfwCreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main-928db7.o
  "_glfwDestroyWindow", referenced from:
      _main in main-928db7.o
  "_glfwInit", referenced from:
      _main in main-928db7.o
  "_glfwMakeContextCurrent", referenced from:
      _main in main-928db7.o
  "_glfwTerminate", referenced from:
      _main in main-928db7.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I get the same error, if I delete the makefile and let VS Code handle the clang stuff.
Does somebody have an idea what to do, it would really help a lot.

Best Regards
Solon

Comment: The errors are self explanatory. It clearly states that you are not linking the library correctly. Give proper paths to your libraries and include directories.

Comment: What do you mean with "proper paths"?

Comment: Did you mean `/lib/` instead of `lib/` in your `#include`?

Comment: @MadScientist Too basic? https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=glfw produces some 7,000 results and a number of them are about install, config, compile, and link

Comment: I added an updated error message

Comment: Don't add "solved" to the title. Instead slap the checkmark next to your answer.

Comment: I don't know what happened to my comment.  Did someone delete it?  I didn't know that was possible.  Anyway, I can't remember exactly what I wrote but as best as I recall yes, IMO the difference between an include file and a library is basic enough that SO is not the right place for that discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I redownloaded the precompiled GLFW-Mac-Binaries, and changed my makefile to the following:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL=main

main:
    clang++ main.cpp -I./lib/GLFW/include/ -L./lib/GLFW/lib-arm64/ -lglfw3 -o main
```

Also my include is now (Only as side note tho):

```
#include "lib/GLFW/include/GLFW/glfw3.h"
```

No the error message is:

```
clang++ main.cpp -I./lib/GLFW/include/ -L./lib/GLFW/lib-arm64/ -lglfw3 -o main
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_CFArrayAppendValue", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayCreateMutable", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayGetCount", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      _closeJoystick in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformPollJoystick in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArrayGetValueAtIndex", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      _closeJoystick in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformPollJoystick in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFArraySortValues", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFBundleCopyPrivateFrameworksURL", referenced from:
      __glfwLoadLocalVulkanLoaderNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CFBundleCopyResourcesDirectoryURL", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CFBundleGetBundleWithIdentifier", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      __glfwInitNSGL in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  "_CFBundleGetDataPointerForName", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CFBundleGetFunctionPointerForName", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      _getProcAddressNSGL in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  "_CFBundleGetMainBundle", referenced from:
      __glfwLoadLocalVulkanLoaderNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CFDictionaryCreateMutable", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFDictionaryGetValue", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CFDictionarySetValue", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFGetTypeID", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFNumberCreate", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFNumberGetValue", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFRelease", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetScancodeName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWHelper selectedKeyboardInputSourceChanged:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      __glfwLoadLocalVulkanLoaderNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformTerminate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      ...
  "_CFRunLoopGetMain", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFRunLoopRunInMode", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFStringCompare", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CFStringCreateWithCString", referenced from:
      _getProcAddressNSGL in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  "_CFStringCreateWithCharactersNoCopy", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetScancodeName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_CFStringGetCString", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetScancodeName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_CFStringGetLength", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CFStringGetMaximumSizeForEncoding", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CFURLCopyLastPathComponent", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent", referenced from:
      __glfwLoadLocalVulkanLoaderNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CFURLGetFileSystemRepresentation", referenced from:
      __glfwLoadLocalVulkanLoaderNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CGAcquireDisplayFadeReservation", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwRestoreVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGAssociateMouseAndMouseCursorPosition", referenced from:
      _updateCursorMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayBounds", referenced from:
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidMove:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetWindowPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidDeminiaturize:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwTransformYNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowSize in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      ...
  "_CGDisplayCopyAllDisplayModes", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayCopyDisplayMode", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayFade", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwRestoreVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayGammaTableCapacity", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayIsAsleep", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModeGetHeight", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModeGetIOFlags", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModeGetRefreshRate", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModeGetWidth", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoModes in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModeRelease", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetVideoMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwRestoreVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayModelNumber", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayMoveCursorToPoint", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayScreenSize", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplaySetDisplayMode", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwRestoreVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayUnitNumber", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGDisplayVendorNumber", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGEventSourceCreate", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CGEventSourceSetLocalEventsSuppressionInterval", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_CGGetDisplayTransferByTable", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetGammaRamp in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGGetOnlineDisplayList", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGMainDisplayID", referenced from:
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidMove:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetWindowPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidDeminiaturize:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwTransformYNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformSetWindowSize in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      ...
  "_CGOpenGLDisplayMaskToDisplayID", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGReleaseDisplayFadeReservation", referenced from:
      __glfwSetVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      __glfwRestoreVideoModeNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGSetDisplayTransferByTable", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetGammaRamp in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_CGWarpMouseCursorPosition", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetCursorPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_IODisplayCreateInfoDictionary", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_IOHIDDeviceCopyMatchingElements", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDDeviceGetProperty", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDDeviceGetValue", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformPollJoystick in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetLogicalMax", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetLogicalMin", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetType", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetTypeID", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetUsage", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDElementGetUsagePage", referenced from:
      _matchCallback in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerCreate", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerOpen", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceMatchingCallback", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerRegisterDeviceRemovalCallback", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerScheduleWithRunLoop", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDManagerSetDeviceMatchingMultiple", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOHIDValueGetIntegerValue", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformPollJoystick in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_IOIteratorNext", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_IOObjectRelease", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_IOServiceGetMatchingServices", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_IOServiceMatching", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_NSApp", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView insertText:replacementRange:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformFocusWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformPollEvents in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformRequestWindowAttention in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformWaitEvents in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformWaitEventsTimeout in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      ...
     (maybe you meant: __OBJC_LABEL_PROTOCOL_$_NSApplicationDelegate, __OBJC_PROTOCOL_$_NSApplicationDelegate )
  "_NSCalibratedRGBColorSpace", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformCreateCursor in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_NSDefaultRunLoopMode", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformPollEvents in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformWaitEvents in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformWaitEventsTimeout in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_NSMouseInRect", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformWindowHovered in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_NSPasteboardTypeString", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformSetClipboardString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetClipboardString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_NSPasteboardURLReadingFileURLsOnlyKey", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView performDragOperation:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_NSSelectorFromString", referenced from:
      -[GLFWApplicationDelegate applicationWillFinishLaunching:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_NSTextInputContextKeyboardSelectionDidChangeNotification", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformInit in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformTerminate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_NSURLPboardType", referenced from:
      -[GLFWContentView initWithGlfwWindow:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSApplication", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSArray", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSAttributedString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBitmapImageRep", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSBundle", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSColor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSCursor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSDate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSDictionary", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSEvent", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSImage", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenu", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMenuItem", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSMutableAttributedString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSNotificationCenter", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSNumber", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWWindowDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWHelper in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWApplicationDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOpenGLContext", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSOpenGLPixelFormat", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSPasteboard", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSScreen", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSString", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSThread", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSTrackingArea", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSURL", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSUserDefaults", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NSWindow", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      objc-class-ref in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSObject", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindowDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWHelper in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWApplicationDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSView", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_NSWindow", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_UCKeyTranslate", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetScancodeName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "___CFConstantStringClassReference", referenced from:
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      CFString in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      ...
  "__objc_empty_cache", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWWindowDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindowDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWHelper in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      ...
  "__objc_empty_vtable", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWWindowDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindowDelegate in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWContentView in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_GLFWWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_GLFWHelper in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      ...
  "_kCFAllocatorDefault", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetScancodeName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwLoadLocalVulkanLoaderNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_init.m.o)
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
      _getProcAddressNSGL in libglfw3.a(nsgl_context.m.o)
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_kCFAllocatorNull", referenced from:
      __glfwPlatformGetScancodeName in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
  "_kCFRunLoopDefaultMode", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_kCFTypeArrayCallBacks", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks", referenced from:
      __glfwInitJoysticksNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_joystick.m.o)
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPop", referenced from:
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidMove:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetWindowPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _updateCursorMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidResignKey:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformIconifyWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformShowWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      ...
  "_objc_autoreleasePoolPush", referenced from:
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidMove:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetWindowPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _updateCursorMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidResignKey:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformIconifyWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformCreateWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformShowWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      ...
  "_objc_enumerationMutation", referenced from:
      __glfwPollMonitorsNS in libglfw3.a(cocoa_monitor.m.o)
  "_objc_msgSend", referenced from:
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidResize:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidMove:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformGetWindowPos in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidDeminiaturize:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      _updateCursorMode in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate windowDidResignKey:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      __glfwPlatformIconifyWindow in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      ...
  "_objc_msgSendSuper2", referenced from:
      -[GLFWWindowDelegate initWithGlfwWindow:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView initWithGlfwWindow:] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView dealloc] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
      -[GLFWContentView updateTrackingAreas] in libglfw3.a(cocoa_window.m.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I didn't really get any smarter from that. I now linked the library as well and didn't only tell the compiler where to search for includes.

**EDIT**

I changed the makefile once again to:

```
.DEFAULT_GOAL=main

main:
    clang++ main.cpp -I./lib/GLFW/include/ -L./lib/GLFW/lib-arm64/ -lglfw3 -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -o main
```

And now it works. The needed frameworks are preinstalled in MacOS and can therefore be used without any installs.

Comment: I have no idea, except to say that clearly there is another library you need to link. I would check the GLFW documentation. that should explain what the GLFW *library dependencies* are on a Mac.

Comment: In fact it's question 4.2 on their FAQ. Admittedly this is just a link to a much longer article. But that's what you should read.

Comment: Yes I was on this FAQ as well. But it only talks about Xcode and I am using VS Code because Xcode is a pain in the ass. And it is talking about these frameworks and I don't really get if I have to install them and how to differentiate if I'm using the static or dynamic library.

Comment: The last section talks about the command line. I'm no Mac expert but I'm pretty sure those are standard frameworks, you don't have to install them, just link with them.

Comment: Currently you are using a static library (though of course you could switch)

Comment: I solved it. Thanks to your hint about the frameworks